# Hosting a configuration file online for an Android application

Tags: android, xml, configuration, hosting

My application have to request some RSS feeds and display the result, i want to be able to add some feeds to the RSS list without modifying the app source code.

The app users will not have the permission to modify the RSS feeds list so i can't implement it in the app.

My idea is to create an xml configuration file and host it online, so the app can access this file on start : this solution let me update the file without updating the application.

But i don't know which online service let me to do that, do you knowa some services that are dedicated for this purpose ? Any proposal will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not being that clear on what you want. As there are many different hosting sites. It seems your looking at just something to host your app underneath the app?? Or were you looking at something else?

Comment: no i'm not looking for something to host the app, it's an Android application so there's no need to host it, i'm just looking for something to host one xml file in a service that will make it available anytime to be retrieved remotly by the android application.

Comment: I've used [this site](http://www.freewebspace.net) before to find web hosting.. and if you were looking for something free I would use [this xml](http://www.xml.in). Because they a free up to 10 gigs